# Positive integer solutions to $y^2=a(1+xy-x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Let $a>3$ be an integer. Define a sequence $X$ as :
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    x_1 & = 1\\
    x_2  & = a-1\\
      x_n & = (a-2)x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}, \ \ n\ge3
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation} if $a$ is **not** a perfect square and

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    x_1 & = 1\\
    x_2  & = \sqrt{a} > 0\\
    x_3 & =a-1\\
    x_4 & =(a-2)\sqrt{a} > 0\\
      x_{2n+1} & = (a-2)x_{2n-1}-x_{2n-3} , \ \ \ \ \ \ \  n\ge 2\\
 x_{2n} & = (a-2)x_{2n-2}-x_{2n-4}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \  n\ge 3
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
if $a$ is a perfect sqaure. From a maple output, it appears the terms of this sequence form a complete solution for $x$ in positive integers for the given diophantine equation $y^2=a(1+xy-x^2)$. How do we go about proving this **i.e**  each term of sequence $X$ is a solution and that these are the only positive solutions. I tried mathematical induction but got stuck.

Comment: This looks like it's related to Pell equations. You might have some luck by poking around there.

Comment: I will need to first revisit Pell equations

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219___2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sketch of the solution via Vieta jumping.

Consider the substitution $u=x$, $v=y-x$. Note that the equation in this case can be rewritten in the following way
$$
(u+v)^2=a(uv+1).
$$
If $a>4$ (otherwise the equation will have only finitely many solutions), then we may suppose that $u,v>0$ (the corresponding solution of the initial equation will be $(x,y)=(u,u+v)$): if $v=0$, then $u=\sqrt{a}$ and if $v<0$, then the only possibility is $u=1$, $v=-1$.

Our equation might be rewritten as quadratic in $u$ (but remember that it's symmetric in $u,v$):
$$
u^2-(a-2)v\cdot u+(v^2-a)=0.
$$
Then the idea is to perform the Vieta jumping: if pair $(u,v)$ is a solution of the equation with $u>v$, then the pair $\left(\frac{v^2-a}{u},v\right)$ is also a solution (note that $\frac{v^2-a}{u}=(a-2)v-u\in\mathbb{Z}$). However, $\frac{v^2-a}{u}<\frac{v^2}{u}<v<u$, so the solution $\left(\frac{v^2-a}{u},v\right)$ is "smaller" than $(u,v)$ (with respect to the sum of coordinates, for example). Now we can do the same with the new solution if $\frac{v^2-a}{u}>0$ and etc.

At some point we must stop and it means that $\frac{v^2-a}{u}<0$ for some solution $(u,v)$ (if $v^2-a=0$, then we reached the solution $(0,\sqrt{a})$). Therefore, $\frac{v^2-a}{u}\le -1$
$$
0=u^2-(a-2)v\cdot u+(v^2-a)\le u^2-(a-2)vu-u=u(u-(a-2)v-1),
$$
so $u\ge (a-2)v+1$. Plugging this inequality to the initial equation we get
$$
0=u^2-(a-2)v\cdot u+(v^2-a)\ge(a-2)v+1+v^2-a=(v-1)^2+a(v-1),
$$
so $v=1$ and $u=a-1$.

**Conclusion.** If $a$ is not a perfect square, then we can reach any positive integer solution via Vieta jumps starting from the $(a-1,1)$. Now if we write formulas for "jumping up", we will obtain your recurrence relations.